# Design decision while using one to one relationship

Tags: oracle, hibernate, data-modeling

I have following entities, I am in doubt about the design design like should `DRIVING_LICENSE` table contain foreign key `PERSON_ID` or `PERSON` table should have `LICENSE_NUMBER` as foreign key from `DRIVING_LICENSE` table?

1. If `PERSON` table has `LICENSE_NUMBER` then `PERSON` table will be child table and `DRIVING_LICENSE` will be parent table, so it implies that when a driving license is deleted then the person should be deleted.
2. On the other way if `DRIVING_LICENSE` will have a `PERSON_ID` then in uni directional one to one relationship in hibernate we will not be able to have a reference of `DrivingLicense` instead we will have a reference of `Person` in `DrivingLicense`, but most of the time it requires that we access `Person` not `DrivingLicense`.

Above two are my main doubts? What is the correct choice and what are its pros and cons?

```
DrivingLicense.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRIVING_LICENSE")
public class DrivingLicense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LICENSE_NUMBER")
    private int licenseNumber;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_ISSUE")
    private Date dateOfIssue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```

and

```
Person.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private int personId;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DrivingLicense drivingLicense;
}
```

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong: when you delete a driving license, you're not forced to delete the person. You just need to set the person's drivingLicense to null. Your second assumption is also strange: the lack of reference to a driving license in Person has nothing to do with where the foreign key is. It has to do with the fact that you explicitely choose to make the association unidirectional. But if the natural navigation is from person to driving license, then go for the first one.

Comment: @JBNizet one more problem here is that if I go with 1st assumption then deleting person is troublesome because I will have to delete driving license first then the person. So what do you suggest is the good practice and which one should I go with while using Unidirectional OneToOne?

Comment: Over their lifetime a Prson may have more than one driver's License e.g. Provisional (while learning) and Full once they passed.  Or say a taxi driver's license.  Regardless of how your model actually implements these details it is not a 1:1 relationship.   More philosophically, a Person applies for a License.  The License doesn't exist before the application.  So whichever way we look at it, PERSON is the parent table and LICENSE is dependent.

Comment: If you want to delete the driving license when deleting the person, the use cascade = REMOVE.

Comment: @JBNizet it will not be possible if I dont have a reference for DrivingLicense in person.

Comment: @JBNizet In unidirectinal OneToOne relationship you can only specify the reference in owning side only.

Comment: Yes, and the owning side, in the first option, is Person. So there's no problem.

Comment: If it were a one-to-many relation where one person could have many licenses, there would be no contest, the foreign key would go in the license table.  The only difference between a one-to-one and a one-to-many relation is the presence of a unique constraint on the foreign key in the child table.

Answer (score 2):

Drivers License should contain a `NOT NULL` foreign key to person with a unique constraint and here's why:

1. Every License ***must*** be associated with a person.
2. A person may have ***zero*** *or* one license associated with them.

Since the license must be associated with a person but a person does not need to have a license, the foreign key should be held by the license table.

The unique constraint on the foreign key will enforce the one-to-one relationship.  Without it you'd have a one-to-many relationship.